# launch an exe/process with stdin stdout and stderr?

Tags: c++, process, stdout, stdin, stderr

With C++ how do i launch an exe/process with stdin stdout and stderr? I know how to do this in .NET and i remember using popen in the past but popen seems to allow stdin OR stdout not both and not all 3.

I need this for windows but a linux solution is welcome as i'll need it for the same project in the future.

Answer (score 3):

You shoud use [CreateProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682425) from WinApi. It takes as argument an object of `struct STARTUP_INFO` type. You can set hStdin, hStdout, and hStderr fields of the object to redirect those streams of child process to file handles you want (file, pipe, socket...)

Answer (score 3):

A portable solution would be [boost.process](http://www.highscore.de/boost/process/process/tutorials.html#process.tutorials.read_from_child)

(Note: this has been proposed as a Boost library, and released under the same license terms, but not officially accepted. See also [Where is Boost.Process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1683665/where-is-boost-process))

Comment: boost process does not implement the Unicode API, only the ANSI API (CreateProcessA), which is a major limitation, making it unsuitable in many cases.

Answer (score 2):

I had troubles with spawning processes and reading or writing to  their stream, but then I discovered a great C++ library which is **very very convenient**.

This open-source project is called [**tiny-process-library**](https://gitlab.com/eidheim/tiny-process-library) and was created by [*eidheim*](https://gitlab.com/eidheim) (a big thanks to him).

> A small platform independent library making it simple to create and
> stop new processes in C++, as well as writing to stdin and reading
> from stdout and stderr of a new process.
>
> #### Features
>
> - No external dependencies
> - Simple to use
> - Platform independent
> - Read separately from stout and stderr using anonymous functions
> - Write to stdin
> - Kill a running process (SIGTERM is supported on Unix-like systems)
> - Correctly closes file descriptors/handles

I am sharing this here because I first come to this thread before finding the library several hours later, so I hope it can save some time for further readers.