# How to test an EXE with Google Test? (2)

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, googletest

I modified one of the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23088252/how-to-test-an-exe-with-google-test/23088515) like

```
std::string path_to_exectuable = "thepath";
TEST(FooTester,CheckHelpScriptReturns0)
{
 using bp =::boost::process; 
 std::vector<std::string> args; args.push_back("--help");
 bp::context ctx; 
 ctx.stdout_behavior = bp::capture_stream(); 

 bp::child c = bp::launch("myExe.exe", args, ctx); 
 EXPECT_EXIT(c.terminate(), ::testing::ExitedWithCode(0), "");
}
```

in the hope to make it more straightforward. However, this wont work,and will output

```
Result: failed to die
```

So, is this approach possible at all, and if yes, what is missing?

Comment: `exec` is undefined. Please post your actual code.

Comment: @MikeKinghan : Please see the code posted in one of the answers in the reference above.

Comment: I did. `exec` is undefined there too. To tell you why *your* code isn't working we need to see it.

Answer (score 1):

The macros [`ASSERT/EXPECT_EXIT(statement, predicate, regex)`](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/AdvancedGuide.md#how-to-write-a-death-test) are satisified
when:-

- Execution of `statement` will cause the test-case process to invoke `exit`
- The return code of `exit` satisifies `predicate`
- `regex` matches the `stderr` output resulting from `statement`

The standard function [`exit(N)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/exit) causes the calling program to terminate normally with return code `N`: hence the [documentation](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/AdvancedGuide.md#how-to-write-a-death-test):

> ::testing::ExitedWithCode(exit_code)
>
> This expression is true if the program exited normally with the given exit code.

The author of the [answer that you want to make "more straightforward"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23089252/1362568)
has sketched a test-case that essentially asserts:-

- If the test-case process launches a `boost::process` `c` and then waits for `c` to finish,
  then `c` will be found to have invoked `exit(0)`.

Which may well be true.

You have written a test case that asserts:-

- If the test-case process launches a `boost::process` `c` and then terminates `c`, with
  `c.terminate()`, then terminating `c` with `c.terminate()` will cause the test-case process to invoke `exit(0)`.

Which is certainly false.

Futhermore, [`c.terminate()`](http://www.highscore.de/boost/process0.5/boost_process/tutorial.html#boost_process.tutorial.terminating_a_program)
does not give `c` the opportunity to eat a last meal, smoke a last cigarette or terminate normally by calling `exit`. It just shoots `c` in the head.
So even if your test case *did* test whether `c` called `exit(0)` as a result of `c.terminate()`, you would find that it doesn't.

Best go with the answer you linked to, as it stands.

**Contd. for OP's comments**

You're hoping to hear how it is possible to apply googletest death-test
macros to death-tests of processes other than the test-case process.
That is not possible. The documentation of death-tests is all [here](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/AdvancedGuide.md#death-tests).
To death-test processes other than the test-case process you'll
have to use the general-purpose `ASSERT/EXPECT` macros, in the way indicated
by the answer you linked to.

Going that way, if you wish to test `s.status()` for any specific terminating signal
conditions then you will need to get the relevant information out of `s.status()`
in an OS-specific manner and `ASSERT/EXPECT` that it what it should
be. If your OS is Posix-conforming (e.g. Linux), then see, for example,
[`boost::process::posix_status`](http://www.highscore.de/boost/process/reference/classboost_1_1process_1_1posix__status.html)

If your target program contains functions or classes whose behaviour
you would like to subject to death-tests then you always have the option
of using googletest to do this in the intended manner, i.e.
by factoring those functions or classes into a library that is linked
by your target program and then death-testing that library with
the death-test macros.

Comment: Well, I was expecting to hear, how it is possible to realize with an **external process**, the suggested approach by the googletest : `TEST(MyDeathTest, NormalExit) {
  EXPECT_EXIT(NormalExit(), ::testing::ExitedWithCode(0), "Success");
}
TEST(MyDeathTest, KillMyself) {
  EXPECT_EXIT(KillMyself(), ::testing::KilledBySignal(SIGKILL), "Sending myself unblockable signal");
}`

verifies that:
    calling `NormalExit()` causes the process to print "Success" to `stderr` and `exit` with `exit code 0`, and
    calling `KillMyself()` kills the process with signal `SIGKILL`