# google test - undefined rerefence when using 2 different projects

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest

I'm trying to use (compile) google test, but having troubles.

I have 1 exe project and another project (google unit test) which have tests for some classes of the first project.

I have tried to use the info from:
[C++ unit test start guide, how to set up Google Test](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/811934/Cplusplus-unit-test-start-guide-how-to-set-up-Goog)

I have 2 c++ projects in my workspace:

1. Exe project name: Tester

   - src folder which contains CElement.cpp, CElement.h, Main.cpp
2. Google test project (exe) name: GoogleTestTester

   - gtest_src folder (contains the gtest)
   - TestElement folder (contains my tests classes)
   - Test1.cpp:

   Test(MyAppTtests, name) 
   {
      CElement* pElm = new CElement();

   ```
   //..
   ```

   }

I'm getting link error (in the GoogleTestTester project): undefined reference to CElement::CElement()

- I have include of "CElement.h" in Test1.cpp
- In the project properties I have include path to the TestElement  folder (which contains CElement.h file)

How can I fix it ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to test an EXE with Google Test?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23088252/how-to-test-an-exe-with-google-test)

Answer (score 0):

Have the test project compile `CElement.cpp` and link the resulting object into the test executable.

If this does not help, or if you do this already, then maybe you declare `CElement::CElement()` in `CElement.h`, but do not define it in `CElement.cpp`.

If this does not help: Your description sounds like you have two sets of the `CElement` files - one set in `Tester/src`, and a copy of this set in `GoogleTestTester/TestElement`. Maybe the copies have diverged and you edited one set but not the other.