# How to run .vbs file in C/C++ and use the result after the execution of .vbs file

Tags: c++, c

How to run vbs file in C/C++ and use the result after the execution of .vbs file

Comment: `popen()` is you friend.

Comment: "*the result*" of the VBS script appears where?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5485923/launch-an-exe-process-with-stdin-stdout-and-stderr

Comment: May be useful link: http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/1087073/How-to-run-vbs-in-Cplusplus-and-use-the-result-aft